# Android:How to stop a run able trigger message in service

Tags: android, service, triggers

i am developing an application that can save the time of user and on that specific time it can trigger the dialogue box but the dialogue box is running nonstop unless the time become unequal`. Please any suggestions?

```
            public void run() {
                // display toast
                hours = dt.getHours();
                minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                String time = hours + ":" + minutes;
                if (getDateTime().equalsIgnoreCase(sharedPrefs.getwakeupTime())) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "it's your wakeup timing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

This is the code that I am getting from Android device:

```
private String getDateTime() {
            // get date time in custom format
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            return sdf.format(new Date());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an Alarm and Receiver for it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Tutorial: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/